# What is an alternative way to tabulate several categorical variables when Stata says there are too many values?

Tags: categorical-data, stata

I have 15 categorical variables that refer to 15 different classes of antibiotics. Each variable has the prefix ab_  (This was done because each patient took usually more than 5 abx so I wasn't sure how to deal with multiple responses)

Possible responses are 0 "none" 1" yes" 2"no" 3"n/a" which indicate whether or not the patient received AB therapy.

When i use the tab command to tabulate all of these together it turns out to be too many values.

I don't want to reshape it because there are 300 patients, but I want to know how many AB each patient took and get a mean from that. How can I do this?

Comment: This is off-topic for this site. Read http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic if in doubt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `egen, anycount()` and `summarize`:

```
clear
set more off

input ///
id ab_1 ab_2 ab_3 ab_4
1 0 3 1 1
2 1 2 3 3
3 1 1 1 0
end

list

egen ab_tot = anycount(ab_*), values(1)
list

summarize ab_tot
```

Comment: Sorry about that, this really helped though- thanks!